# Find references of a private member in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis, member, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to find all the references of a private member of a class.
I've tried to do this:

```
MemberInfo member = ...//the private member for which I want to find its references 
Type type = member.DeclaringType;
string assemblyName = type.Assembly.GetName().Name;
Solution solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
Project project = solution.Projects.First(x => x.AssemblyName == assemblyName);
Compilation compilation = project.GetCompilation();
ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration = compilation.GetClassDeclaration(type);
MemberDeclarationSyntax memberDeclaration = classDeclaration.GetMemberDeclaration(member.Name);
SemanticModel semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree);
ISymbol memberSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberDeclaration).Symbol; ==> this is null since GetSymbolInfo does not expect a MemberDeclaationSyntax
IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(memberSymbol, solution).Result;
```

How can I find all the references of the private member?

Answer (score 0):

Because `MemberDeclarationSyntax` is a SyntaxNode, you need to use the `Semantic.GetDeclaredSymbol` method to get the symbol associated with this node. For example:

```
var memberDeclarationSyntax = ( MemberDeclarationSyntax ) root.FindNode( diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan );
var declaredSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol( memberDeclarationSyntax );
var references = await SymbolFinder
    .FindReferencesAsync( declaredSymbol , context.Document.Project.Solution )
    .ConfigureAwait( false );
```